# Hide scrollbar one A element, but show it on B element

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I have an HTML page that contains a block that contains another block.
I need to show the scrollbar on block A while I want to hide it on block B, but it is still scrollable, just like removing the background of the scrollbar.
(Block B is located inside block A)

But in fact, I can't hide the scrollbar. At the top of my code, I need to declare this globally because it is used in some of another blocks (Which block A need)

```
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  }
```

Here's the things I've tried :

1. Rewrite scrollbar in the element

```
.myElement {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
  }
}
```

2. Using `scrollbar-color`

```
.myElement {
  scrollbar-color : transparent;
}
```

3. Using `scrollbar-width`

```
.myElement {
  scrollbar-width : none;
}
```

But not a single one of those things works. Has anyone had the same experience? Please let me know how you fix it guys

Answer (score 0):

Your 1. solution is correct, but with small change.

Go from this

```
.myElement {
  ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /*anything you want to do*/
  }
}
```

To this

```
.myElement::-webkit-scrollbar {
    /*anything you want to do*/
}
```

Comment: Wow, just simple as that! THANKS!